# in OPL Filter and read k for a set of i,j from a tuple having i,j,k

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

I have a model reading data from an excel file. Below is part of the model.

I use the below code to read data as below

```
    tuple blockType {
        string id;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
     };
     
    
    
    {blockType} PitBlocksType = ...; // Read from excel table which contains several rows, a short example below

/*
Example below
Block Id    Bench(i)    Strip(j)    Block(k)
P1           1             1        1
P2           1             1        2
P3           1             1        3
P7           3             1        1
P8           3             1        2
P9           3             1        3
P10          1             2        1
P11          1             2        2
P12          1             2        3
P16          3             2        1   
P17          3             2        2
P18          3             2        3
P19          1             3        1
P20          1             3        2
P21          1             3        3
P22          2             3        1
P23          2             3        2
P24          2             3        3
P25          3             3        1
P26          3             3        2
P27          3             3        3    
    */

    tuple jk {
        string ids;
        int j;
        int k;
    }
    
    {jk} jks=...; // from the above table reading only the j,k : There are multiple occurrences of the same j,k - Not sure if this is the best method


    {int} BenchPerjk[jks]= ?????? ;   // Here I want to read all i for each set of jks

    //int succ3=next(BenchPerjk[<id, 5,3>],3); // I want to use something like this below
    
    
    {blockType} OntopPit[b1 in PitBlocksType] =
         {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == next(BenchPerjk[b.id, b.j ,b.k],b.i) &&   // This is giving an error
                            ((b1.k  == b.k-1 ) ||
                             (b1.k  == b.k+1 ) ||
                             (b1.k  == b.k )  ) &&
                            ((b1.j  == b.j-1 ) ||
                             (b1.j  == b.j+1 ) ||
                             (b1.j  == b.j )  ) };
```

There are 2 issues above - One is How to read the BenchPerjk[jks] by filtering data from the table for each set of jk.

The second issue is the implementation of the Next command in the code - What is the best way.

Looking forward for your help please,

Comment: I posted an answer for the first part but I am not clear what the `next()` function should yield for a block `b` in your case. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Thank you Daniel, it is so helpful. I have posted a comment below your answer

Comment: more details also in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989416/skip-missing-data-from-table-in-opl-model

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter things while reading, so you always have to read everything. Once you have everything you should be able extract the `jks` as follows:

```
tuple jk {
  int j;
  int k;
}

{jk} jks = { <t.j, t.k> | t in PitBlocksType };

execute { writeln(jks); }

{int} BenchPerjk[v in jks] = { t.i | t in PitBlocksType : t.j == v.j && t.k == v.k };

execute { writeln(BenchPerjk); }
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel for the Quick response. I have been able to get the jks and BenchPerjk reported as : jks - {<1 1> <1 2> <1 3> <2 1> <2 2> <2 3> <3 1> <3 2> <3 3>}
 benchPerjk - [{1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3}]

Comment: However, I was originally trying with a code {blockType} OntopPit[b1 in PitBlocksType] =
     {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == b.i +1 &&
                        ((b1.k  == b.k-1 ) ||
                         (b1.k  == b.k+1 ) ||
                         (b1.k  == b.k )  ) &&
                        ((b1.j  == b.j-1 ) ||
                         (b1.j  == b.j+1 ) ||
                         (b1.j  == b.j )  ) };                       // In this I wanted to replace the b.i+1 with the next i in the BenchPerjk . I need to use the Next command. Can you please suggest

Comment: The b.i+1 works well to generate the OntopPit if I have continuous i like all i = 1,2,3 present for all sets of j,k. However as you will see in the data for some sets of j,k i is only 1 and 3, with 2 missing

Comment: I tried {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == next(BenchPerjk[< b.j , b.k>],b.i)  && ......... I could run this , but came up with 2 lines of error                                                                                                   
"b.i" : next() element does not exist.  and  2nd line : Invalid initialization expression for array item: OntopPit[<"P1",1,1,1>].

Comment: More details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62989416/skip-missing-data-from-table-in-opl-model

Comment: Things get a bit confusing here and your OPL code is hard to read in your comments above. I suggest you create a minimal example that does not work and cannot be answered by this and the referenced question and then you ask a new question with that. Btw, before you do that, maybe you can use the `last()` and `first()` functions to check whether you are at the first or last element of a set and for these elements avoid querying the next or previous element?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion Daniel. I have reposted the issue again on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931583/find-next-number-for-sets-in-opl  It should be clear there