# Find next number for sets in OPL

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, opl

I have 2 sets as below

```
jks - {<1 1> <1 2> <1 3> <2 1> <2 2> <2 3> <3 1> <3 2> <3 3>} 
benchPerjk - [{1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3}]
```

I now want to find the next number in the benchPerjk for a certain jks

The code is as below

```
tuple jk {
  int j;
  int k;
}

{jk} jks = { <t.j, t.k> | t in PitBlocksType };

{int} BenchPerjk[v in jks] = { t.i | t in PitBlocksType : t.j == v.j && t.k == v.k };
```

---

Where the PitBlocksType come from the following data :

---

```
 tuple blockType {
        string id;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
     };
     
    
    
    {blockType} PitBlocksType = ...; // Read from excel table which contains several rows, a short example below

/*
Example below
Block Id    (i)       (j)      (k)
P1           1             1        1
P2           1             1        2
P3           1             1        3
P7           3             1        1
P8           3             1        2
P9           3             1        3
P10          1             2        1
P11          1             2        2
P12          1             2        3
P16          3             2        1   
P17          3             2        2
P18          3             2        3
P19          1             3        1
P20          1             3        2
P21          1             3        3
P22          2             3        1
P23          2             3        2
P24          2             3        3
P25          3             3        1
P26          3             3        2
P27          3             3        3    
    */
```

---

The reason why I am lookng for this is I want to use the BenchPerjk to find the next i. for using in the code below in place of the b.i+1

The b.i+1 works well if the i is continuous and all i is present for any set of j,k. Which means if Benchperjk would be

benchPerjk - [{1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3} {1 2 3}]

But that is not the case in my data.

```
{blockType} OntopPit[b1 in PitBlocksType] =
     {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == b.i +1 &&
                        ((b1.k  == b.k-1 ) ||
                         (b1.k  == b.k+1 ) ||
                         (b1.k  == b.k )  ) &&
                        ((b1.j  == b.j-1 ) ||
                         (b1.j  == b.j+1 ) ||
                         (b1.j  == b.j )  ) };
```

Suggestions please.

I have tried the following code but it comes up with errors :

```
{blockType} OntopPit[b1 in PitBlocksType] =
      {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == next(BenchPerjk[< b.j , b.k>],b.i) &&
                        ((b1.k  == b.k-1 ) ||
                         (b1.k  == b.k+1 ) ||
                         (b1.k  == b.k )  ) &&
                        ((b1.j  == b.j-1 ) ||
                         (b1.j  == b.j+1 ) ||
                         (b1.j  == b.j )  ) };
```

but came up with 2 lines of error
"b.i" : next() element does not exist.
Invalid initialization expression for array item: OntopPit[<"P1",1,1,1>]

Answer (score 1):

you could use next:

```
tuple jk {
  int j;
  int k;
}

{jk} jks = {<1 ,1> ,<1 ,2>, <1 ,3>, <2, 1> ,<2 ,2> ,<2, 3>, <3, 1> ,<3, 2>, <3, 3>};

{int} BenchPerjk[jks] = [{1 ,3}, {1, 3}, {1, 3} ,{1 ,3}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}, {1 ,2 ,3} ,{1 ,2, 3} ,{1 ,2, 3}];

// Now suppose you want to get the next after 1 for <j,k> = <2,1>

int res=next(BenchPerjk[<2,1>],1);

execute
{
  writeln(res);
}
```

gives 3

Something more generic was later required:

```
tuple jk {
  int j;
  int k;
}

{jk} jks = {<1 ,1> ,<1 ,2>, <1 ,3>, <2, 1> ,<2 ,2> ,<2, 3>, <3, 1> ,<3, 2>, <3, 3>};

{int} BenchPerjk[jks] = [{1 ,3}, {1, 3}, {1, 3} ,{1 ,3}, {1, 3}, {1, 3}, {1 ,2 ,3} ,{1 ,2, 3} ,{1 ,2, 3}];

// Now suppose you want to get the next after 1 for <j,k> = <2,1>

int res=next(BenchPerjk[<2,1>],1);

execute
{
  writeln(res);
}

// And now as a generic function

{int} benches=union (jk in jks) BenchPerjk[jk];

int nextone[jk in jks][i in benches]=(i in BenchPerjk[jk])?((i!=last(BenchPerjk[jk]))?next(BenchPerjk[jk],i):-2):-1;



int res2=nextone[<2,1>][1];

execute
{
  writeln(res2);
}
```

gives

3
3

Comment: Thank you Alex for the response. I get the idea on implementing for a static value of <2,1>,1 . However in the code I want to apply it using variabes something like:                {b | b in PitBlocksType: b1.i == next(BenchPerjk[< b.j , b.k>],b.i)                                          Where instead of  <2,1> I could have any number coming up from b.j and b.k,   and i need the next i after b.i            I am finding it difficult to implement this

Comment: Added in the question about what I have tried so far